# Debian jessie : OpenLDAP Server how to add new schema?

Tags: debian, cisco, ldap, openldap, schema

The following items are schema of context. I will add

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.3
  NAME 'CiscoDomain'
  DESC 'Domain for VPN users'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.4
  NAME 'CiscoDNS'
  DESC 'DNS server for VPN users'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.5
  NAME 'CiscoIPAddress'
  DESC 'Address for VPN user'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.6
  NAME 'CiscoIPNetmask'
  DESC 'Address for VPN user'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.7
  NAME 'CiscoSplitACL'
  DESC 'Split tunnel list for VPN users'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.8
  NAME 'CiscoSplitTunnelPolicy'
  DESC 'Split tunnel policy for VPN users'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.9
  NAME 'CiscoGroupPolicy'
  DESC 'Group policy for VPN users'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.2.1 NAME 'CiscoPerson'
        DESC 'My cisco person'
        AUXILIARY
        MUST ( sn $ cn )
        MAY ( userPassword $ telephoneNumber $ seeAlso
            $ description $ CiscoBanner $ CiscoACLin $ CiscoDomain
            $ CiscoDNS $ CiscoIPAddress $ CiscoIPNetmask $ CiscoSplitACL
            $ CiscoSplitTunnelPolicy $ CiscoGroupPolicy ) )
```

The `~# vi /usr/share/slapd/slapd.conf` command produces the following output:

```
# Global Directives:
# Features to permit
#allow bind_v2
# Schema and objectClass definitions<br>
include /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema<br>
include /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema<br>
include /etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema<br>
include /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema<br>
include /etc/ldap/schema/cisco.schema<br>
```

There were paired every schema ldif that have file ldif for your schema file generation know what way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure, that your attribute types do not exist in your existing OpenLDAP installation or any that you will connect (look for conflicting OIDs!), you can just add a custom schema. This is a cleaner way than messing around with the core schemas.

You can do this very easily by adding a node to your `cn=config` backend:

`dn: cn=<yourSchemaName>,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: <yourSchemaName>
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.3 NAME 'CiscoDomain'...`

Of course you can also use the old config backend and restart slapd.